# PyQt5 application: button press event not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have reduced my application as much as I can.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Controller3:
    def __init__(self, view):
        view.searchBtn.clicked.connect(self.onSearchClicked)
        
    def onSearchClicked(self):
        print("Search")
        
class Window3(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.searchBtn = QPushButton("Search")
        layout.addWidget(self.searchBtn)

        self._centralWidget.setLayout(layout)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = Window3()

    Controller3(view)
    
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This variant is not working.

But, adding useless second unhandled button makes an application to work!

```
import sys
from functools import partial


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Controller3:
    def __init__(self, view):
        view.searchBtn.clicked.connect(self._onSearchClicked)
        
        #Here is the difference! It only works with partial!    
        view.tubearea.clicked.connect(partial(self.func1, ""))

    def func1(self, name):
        print("FlowClicked" + name)
        
    def _onSearchClicked(self):
        print("Search")
        
class Window3(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.searchBtn = QPushButton("Search")
        layout.addWidget(self.searchBtn)
        
        self.tubearea = QPushButton("HELLO")

        
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(layout)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = Window3()

    Controller3(view)
    
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Change to `controller = Controller3(view)`.

Comment: Oh. The answer is so simple. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Without a reference (including using a local variable), the instance of `Controller3` gets immediately garbage collected, so the signal connection is discarded. Using `partial` prevents that, as it creates a reference that makes the object persistent. Always create a reference, even if it's a local variable, unless you *really* know what you're doing.